# InstallShield exisiting application checking

Tags: installshield-2011

I have two different versions (Basic and Professional) of my application. I have created two different setup projects for both the versions. I want to restrict the user to install only one version per system. If user has the Basic version and he tries installing the professional version I have to uninstall the basic version.

Can anybody tell me how I can check the registry entry for my basic version and uninstall if the user tries to install the professional version?  I also have to do vice versa.

I am using InstallShield 2011 and my project type is BASIC MSI.

Early help would be appreciated..

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would consider is to use Major Upgrades. You can then choose whether to use the  same upgrade code for both editions, or to use two different ones and have Upgrade entries for the other edition (in addition to its own).

If you do want to allow a cross-edition downgrade while disallowing a same-edition downgrade, use two different upgrade codes. If you want to disallow any version downgrade, cross-edition or otherwise, either option will work (I would tend to suggest different codes for clarity, but it's not critical).

Comment: You mean each build should I change the Upgrade code for both the version.? How to handle the downgrade.? could you please explain me little more

Comment: See http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14helplib/PreventingDowngrades.htm for information preventing downgrades; this strategy applies equally well whether it's for your UpgradeCode or for someone else's. For lower versions, you can choose whether you also want to block, or automatically uninstall and replace the existing package.

Comment: And no, I don't mean each build should use a different UpgradeCode. Just each edition should probably have its own code so you can decide how to handle different cross-edition scenarios without having to pre-determine the list of ProductCodes.

Comment: Thanks Michael..It work well..I have two different shortcut for both revision, after overwriting icons are not removed..Is there anything I supposed to do for that to removed the desktop shortcuts and start menu short cut.?